# Should redirecting to a splash page/system (users who are not shibboleth authenticated) be done at apache or application level

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, shibboleth

Right now, when the user visits my site abc.com, shibd (which is a daemon running on the server) will intercept and redirect the non shib authenticated users to the authentication page.

I want the user to go to a splash page instead.  The tricky part is that the splash page/system is a different codebase than the "actual" application.

I created a virtual host for the actual application, and I have an Alias declaration which will correctly route the user to my splash page when the user types abc.com/splash into their browser.  But if I want to redirect unauthenticated traffic to /splash when they hit abc.com, would it be best practice to do that within the "actual" application, or is there some simple additional apache directive that I can use?

Also, I can't modify the application core (index.php, .htaccess), so that makes me lean towards an apache based solution if possible.

Comment: Maybe apache could redirect to splash when it sees a redirect request to authentication page coming from localhost (shibd) but honestly, this is an ugly hack and I would not recommend it. Why can't you modify the application?

Comment: I don't maintain the "actual" application.  We use a package manager to update core, so my changes would be overwritten  by an update.

At this point, I am trying to see if my scenario is possible without using hacks.